# Display real date and time and change it when user selects another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have to display within a div the current Date and Time, with the seconds refreshing when the page loads, and change it when the user selects another one from de Date and Time picker, im trying to do it with this Script but nothing happens. The part with de .datetimepicker si for the calendar to show that works correctly but the second one is what im using to try to get the real date and time and it´s not working. Can You Please Help Me?

Thank you so much

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#date-time').datetimepicker();
});
var momentNow = moment();
$('#date-time').html(momentNow.format('YYYY MMMM DD' + 'A hh:mm:ss'));
```

////

UPDATE

[When the page loads it should look like this with the real time and date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Jpj.png)

[Then when he clicks on the div it shows the calendar and time so that he can make a selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDDd7.png)

Thanks

Comment: Which datetimepicker() plugin are you using? Also, what do you mean with "when the user selects *another one*"? Please [share a minimal, complete and verifiable example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce the problem and help out.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer i´ll include some sceenshots within the post to explain better what im trying to make, i´m using a plug in i found on internet that has it´s own js file + Jquery.js + jquery-ui.js

Comment: Screenshots can help but we prefer actual code (including scripts and CSS files) so, as mentioned above, we can reproduce the issue. We don't know which libraries you're using on your project so it's a little bit difficult to help without seeing some more code.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Tania696/pen/BrOKRQ i can´t make the calendar show in the code pen editor but in my computer it does like the images above. here is the link that has the js that makes it function https://rgov-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/tania_martinez_rgov_mx/EbxiIdyCwqFPoDyH-zANkfcBj_5ceUKRrt2XaYrx8LCuoQ?e=X69JUa i hope this helps im really new at this field :/ Thanks

Comment: Ok, so you're basically trying to combine moment.js with a datepicker? What should happen when someone selects a date?

Comment: Yeah that´s what im trying to do, when someone picks a date and an hour it should replace the moment date and time.... :0

Comment: Alright then, please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This updates the time in the datetime field every second (like a clock), and also allows the user to select a date and time (in which case the clock will stop working as we're selecting a different date & time than the current one):

```
<form method="post" action="?">
   <div>
     <label for="filter-date">
       <span><img src="images/calendar.png" alt=""></span>
     </label>

     <input type="text" name="filter-date" id="date-time"/>
   </div>
</form>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var timer;
        //var momentNow = moment();

        var dateTimeClock = $('#date-time').datetimepicker({
            format:'Y F d H:i:s A', // Use the same date format as the one set with moment()
            onSelectDate: function(ct, $i){
                // Stop the clock
                if (timer) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
            }
        });

        // This function updates the datetime field 
        // every one second, simulating a clock.
        function clock(){
            if (timer)
                clearInterval(timer);

            timer = setInterval(function(){
                dateTimeClock.val(moment().format('YYYY MMMM DD' + ' hh:mm:ss A'));
            }, 1000);
        }

        // Start the clock
        clock();

    });
</script>
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e8p1qwuu/28/).

If you have any comments / questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Hi Hector i can see it working correctly in the jsfiddle but in my html it still doesn´t display the current date and hour :(

Comment: Is your site available somewhere online? if so, please share the URL so I can have a look.

Comment: I´m sorry my mistake i forgot the moment.js, one last question how can i put it in DDMMYYYY format ? Thank you so much

Comment: No problem! If this answer helped you, please consider marking it as "Accepted" (you should see a "tick" mark right next to it). Regarding your question, if you want to change the date to DDMMYYYY format after selecting a date from the calendar, change `format:'Y F d H:i:s A'` to `format:'dmY'`.

Comment: Done! i cant rate it because i´m a newbie here but i marked it as accepted, really thank you so much (:D